# Best coding practice for closing of FileOutputStream at various location

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

```
properties.storeToXML(new FileOutputStream(new File(m_wcontext.getProject().getBaseDirectory() +
         "/" + m_wcontext.getServiceName() + ".properties")),null);
```

I have a similar method call at 10 different places. During the code review it was suggested that I need to close the resource. The recommended method was to use modify the code as below: but that will make the code clumsy as I need to repeat the code 10 times.

```
try {
    fios = new FileOutputStream(new File(m_wcontext.getProject().getBaseDirectory() +
                "/" + m_wcontext.getServiceName() + ".properties"));
    properties.storeToXML(fios, null);
} finally {
    if(fios!=null) {
         fios.close();
    }
}
```

Will the below approach is fine. is there anything better?

```
    FileOutputStream fios = getFileOutPutStream(m_wcontext.getProject().getBaseDirectory()  +  "/" + m_wcontext.getServiceName() + ".properties");        
    properties.storeToXML(fios, null);

    // ...      

private FileOutputStream getFileOutPutStream(String path) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fios=null;
    try {
        fios = new FileOutputStream(new File(m_wcontext.getProject().getBaseDirectory() +
                "/" + m_wcontext.getServiceName() + ".properties"));
        properties.storeToXML(fios, null);
    } finally {
        if(fios!=null) {
            fios.close();
        }
    }
    return fios;
}
```

Comment: What java version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're compiling with Java 7 or above, you can use a `try-with-resources` statement to automatically close the resource:

```
private void writeXML(String path) throws IOException {
    try (FileOutputStream fios = new FileOutputStream(new File(path))) {
        properties.storeToXML(fios, null);
    }
}
```

I've made the method `void`, as it looks like you have no need for the `FileOutputStream` after passing it as an argument to `storeToXML`.

To call this method, you can use the following:

```
String path = m_wcontext.getProject().getBaseDirectory() +
            File.separator + m_wcontext.getServiceName() + ".properties";

try {
    writeXML(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: let us assuem, if the file which is written is very large and the file is being written, and meanwhile, another method calls this same writeXML method will that scenario be handled here? i.e will both resources be closed on completion of the tasks.

Comment: That depends on the implementation of `storeToXML`.  As long as the files are different and you buffer the writing appropriately, I don't see why it wouldn't work.  But yes, both resources will be closed after writing to the file(s).